# Samsung Galaxy S3 doesn't mount external SD card

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, external-sd, sd-card, 4.3-jelly-bean

I've recently flashed the stock firmware onto my Samsung Galaxy S3 because there was one feature which didn't work on CyanogenMod. My external SD card worked fine until recently - the 'mount SD card' option in Settings is now grayed out, and whenever I insert the SD card into the device, the following messages appear in the logcat:

```
W/MountService( 3370): Failed to mount media on insertion
W/MountService( 3370): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/MountService( 3370):     at com.android.server.MountService.doMountVolume(MountService.java:1212)
W/MountService( 3370):     at com.android.server.MountService.doMountVolume(MountService.java:1288)
W/MountService( 3370):     at com.android.server.MountService.access$2100(MountService.java:134)
W/MountService( 3370):     at com.android.server.MountService$6.run(MountService.java:1021)
```

My computer seems to recognise the SD card just fine. Can anyone help me with solving this problem?

**Update 1**: I was successful in mounting the SD card manually using the shell command from this tutorial: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1804573, however it was only accessible to apps with root permissions.

**Update 2**: As suggested in the comments section, I formatted the card in question to exFAT. The problem persists.

**Update 3**: The `dmesg` (`/proc/kmsg`) file seemed to have some relevant information. This is what got logged into it when I removed then inserted the card:

```
<6>[ 5096.384848] c2 mmc1: card removed.
<6>[ 5096.385093] c0 mmc1: card e624 removed
<6>[ 5096.478613] c0 sdhci_set_ios : MMC Card OFF samsung-hsmmc
<6>[ 5097.221780] c2 mmc1: card removed.
<6>[ 5097.221830] c2 mmc1: card inserted.
<6>[ 5097.421722] c2 sdhci_set_ios : MMC Card ON samsung-hsmmc
<6>[ 5097.450386] c0 mmc1: cmd 52 command timeout error
<6>[ 5097.450735] c0 mmc1: cmd 52 command timeout error
<6>[ 5097.454610] c0 mmc1: cmd 5 command timeout error
<6>[ 5097.454944] c0 mmc1: cmd 5 command timeout error
<6>[ 5097.455274] c0 mmc1: cmd 5 command timeout error
<6>[ 5097.455606] c0 mmc1: cmd 5 command timeout error
<6>[ 5097.599241] c2 mmc1: new high speed SDHC card at address e624
<6>[ 5097.600105] c3 mmcblk1: mmc1:e624 SU32G 29.7 GiB
<6>[ 5097.614116] c3  mmcblk1: p1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138150/discussion-on-question-by-arielle-samsung-galaxy-s3-doesnt-mount-external-sd-ca).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem just by flashing the stock firmware (using Odin) again. I didn't even have to wipe `/data` - all my apps are still there.